# Does Datetime update inside a function

Tags: python-3.x, function, python-datetime

I have a function that runs in a loop (calls the function after a wait time) and that function needs to pull data from DateTime ie. current day, month, and year. My question is if it is outside the function will it update or do I need to have it inside the function for that to happen. I do not have a root.mainloop() as it is all called from functions. I am new to python and have looked around but can not find this answer.

I am using Python 3.7 and have imported all the necessary modules.

Sample code:

```
    today1 = date.today()
    today = today1.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
    year = date.today().year
    month = date.today().month
    day = date.today().day

    def function1():
        if month >= 7:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtDateFrom"]').send_keys(str(month-6) + '/' + 
            str(day) + '/' + str(year-1))
        else:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtDateFrom"]').send_keys(str(month+6) + '/' + 
            str(day) + '/' + str(year-2))
    waittime()

    def waittime():
         time.sleep(300)
         function1()

    function1()
```

Comment: The constants like `today1` are defined when the line of code is executed - why do you think they are executed again when you call some function somewhere else in the code? So no, these variables won't update unless you have an outer loop that runs these lines again. Also a general thing, you don't pass any parameters to your functions - although that works (taking from the outer scope), I'd consider it bad practice as it makes the code hard to read.

Comment: @MrFuppes thank you for your answer. As I mentioned I am fairly new to python and do not know much of anything. I will have to research what parameters I am supposed to be passing into my functions. I do this as a hobby, so anything to make my code run smoother and better is a gift to me. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: maybe [this](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) is helpful to dig into variable scope in Python.